# Poky-sumo : nothing provides kernel-module-hello... error

Tags: kernel-module, yocto, bitbake

we are currently updating our poky environment to the sumo branch and one of our recipes that build a kernel module does not work anymore. I get the following error when building image rootfs :

```
- nothing provides kernel-module-ourmodule-4.14.73-linux4sam_6.0-00005-g871f191fa293 needed by ourmodule.ourtarget
```

This recipe was working with previous version of yocto.

For testing, I made a copy of meta-skeleton/recipes-kernel/hello-mod in our layer, added hello-mod package in our image and built the image. I have the same kind of error:

```
Collected errors:
 * Solver encountered 1 problem(s):
 * Problem 1/1:
 *   - nothing provides kernel-module-hello-4.14.73-linux4sam_6.0-00005-g871f191fa293 needed by hello-mod-0.1-r0.our_target
 * 
 * Solution 1:
 *   - do not ask to install a package providing hello-mod
```

Any help is welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In My case it was the following issue:

I had the module installed in a non standard `kernel-module dir`, when removing this it was fixed by adding

```
RPROVIDES_${PN} += "kernel-module-${PN}"
```

to the recipe.